# Opening Single Child form at a time in VB.NET MDI form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sharpdevelop

I am trying to keep only one active child at a time. I want to dispose other child when opening any child in MDI form.
I have tried many possible way without luck. It would be nice to have a separate class function to do the dirty work. Any help will be highly appreciated.
Here is the sample code form class:

Imports System.Reflection

```
Class closeHelper

    Public Shared Sub HideAllForms()
        Dim currentAssembly As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        Dim count As Integer = Application.OpenForms.Count
        For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1 Step +1
            Dim f As Form = Application.OpenForms(i)
            If f.[GetType]().Assembly Is currentAssembly AndAlso f.Name <> "frmMDI" Then 'Here 'frmMDI' is the name of mdiform.
                f.Close()
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I am getting following error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Always do a **reverse** loop when deleting. `For i As Integer = (count - 1) To 0 Step -1` Basic knowledge.

Comment: Yes I know that, however I thought It may help to reach till count. I tried again and result is same. Got the Error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index" at Application.OpenForms(i) with i underlined. ({"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"})

Comment: This code belongs in the MDI parent form.  Then it is simply `For Each child In Me.MdiChildren.ToList(): child.Close(): Next`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One should always use a reverse loop when deleting or doing an action that will modify the collection.

```
For i As Integer = (count - 1) To 0 Step -1
```

Picture this (a collection of `3` items) using a forward loop:

1. iteration: Delete/close index 0, indices available: 0, 1, 2, Result: OK.
2. iteration: Delete/close index 1, indices available: 0, 1, Result: OK.
3. iteration: Delete/close index 2, indices available: 0, Result: Error.

As you can see, the last will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score 1):

You generally should not modify a collection in the same loop in which you are iterating over it.

What happens is that after closing a form, it's no longer part of OpenForms collection, so you sort of skip every other form. And then it fails half way through, because the indexes are off. For example, suppose you have 3 forms. At index 0, you will close form #1, shifting all open forms by 1. At index 1 you have form #3 (because #2 is now under 0) and you close it. Then trying to close form at index #3, but it's not there, and you only have 1 item in your collection now (so one form remains open and you also get an exception).

Instead, copy OpenForms into an array of Form, and do the same procedure.

```vb
Public Shared Sub HideAllForms()
  Dim currentAssembly As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

  'remember which forms were open, we don't want to mess our indexes  
  Dim forms As New List(Of Form)
  For Each frm in Application.OpenForms
    forms.Add(frm)
  Next

  'iterate over all forms which were open at the start of this method
  For Each f As Form in forms
    If f.[GetType]().Assembly Is currentAssembly AndAlso f.Name <> "HOME" Then 'Here 'HOME' is the name of mdiform.
      f.Close()
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to except this answer but the answer is already in my code. The only problem with your and mine code is, It will close and reopen the same form if I hit the button twice, Here is the calling code : closeHelper.HideAllForms()
            form2.Show()

Comment: @SOAMad: You already accepted an answer. There cannot be more than one accepted answer on SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Private Sub ToolStrip1_ItemClicked(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles ToolStrip.ItemClicked

Dim ToolStripClickedItem As String = e.ClickedItem.Name
    Select Case ToolStripClickedItem
        Case "ToolStripButtonEmployee"
            For Each f As Form In Application.OpenForms
                If TypeOf f Is frmEmployee Then
                    f.Activate()
                    Return
                End If
            Next

            Dim childEmployee As New frmEmployee
            childEmployee.MdiParent = Me
            childEmployee.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
            childEmployee.Show()
End sub
```

I have called it from `ToolStripButtonEmployee.ToolStrip1_ItemClicked` Event

Comment: Kumari thanks kindly let me know if you can do soem freelance

Answer (score 0):

Well, the below code is working for me. The only problem is if I click on button to open the current form again, it seems like it reopen the form. I ill test it few more times.

```
Public Shared Sub HideAllForms()
        Dim currentAssembly As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        Dim count As Integer = Application.OpenForms.Count
        For i As Integer = (count - 1) To 0 Step -1
            Dim f As Form = Application.OpenForms(i)
            If f.[GetType]().Assembly Is currentAssembly AndAlso f.Name <> "HOME" Then 'Here 'HOME' is the name of mdiform.
                f.Close()
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: So it did work? (referring to your comment) Maybe I should post the answer I'd written? (but didn't post since you stated it didn't work)